# How to create a `if` statement dynamically in R?

Tags: if-statement, tidyverse

How to make the following code more concise, so as not to repeat the `if` statement three times?

```r
txtA <- "text A"
txtB <- "text B"
txtC <- "text C"

section <- "B"

# How to make the following code in a more programmatic manner?
if (section == "A") txtA <- tolower(txtA)
if (section == "B") txtB <- tolower(txtB)
if (section == "C") txtC <- tolower(txtC)
```

I don't expect a simple `dplyr::case_when` but something that also does the `txtXX <- tolower(txtXX)` more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if I got your goal correct and you simply want to get rid of the explicit if statements?
I would suggest collecting all 'paragraphs' in a single object first for easier handling.

```r
all_txt <- list(
  A = "text A",
  B = "text B",
  C = "text C"
)
section <- 'B'
all_txt[[section]] <- tolower(all_txt[[section]])
all_txt
```

Comment: Just add `list2env(all_txt, envir = .GlobalEnv)` to add the variables to the environment.

Comment: I would actually prefer to keep everything in a single list that you can easily map over instead of cluttering the workspace with individual objects. however, list2env() may come in handy in other cases indeed